# How to reshape data from 1d array to a 2d matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have data loaded from a database in the form of a list of tuples, such as:

```py
[
("Label", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0),
("Label", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0),
("Label", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0),
]
```

The data is obviously not all the same. I want to split the data into a 2d matrix, such that I can isolate certain columns so I can feed it into a keras model. Specifically, I want columns 1-5, and 6-10 into separate buckets, as they will be inputs to the model. I know that I can do this for a 2d matrix by doing `arr[:,[1,2,3,4,5]]`. This failed for me when I tried it. I imagine this failed because I have a list of tuples, but I honestly don't know.

I have tried just doing `np.reshape(arr,(12,len(arr))`, but that gave an error of `cannot reshape array of size 7826 into shape (12,7826)`. How do I reshape this 1d array into a 2d matrix?

Edit:
arr as referenced was created using the following command, where data is a list of tuples. If it matters, the data was gather from a sqlite database fetchall()

```py
    dataType = np.dtype(
        [
            ("matchId", str, 14),
            ("100-1", int),
            ("100-2", int),
            ("100-3", int),
            ("100-4", int),
            ("100-5", int),
            ("200-1", int),
            ("200-2", int),
            ("200-3", int),
            ("200-4", int),
            ("200-5", int),
            ("sideWon", int),
        ]
    )
    arr = np.fromiter(data, dtype=dataType)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `data was just simple a 1d list`? data is not your list of tuples?

Comment: data is my list of tuples. I meant more in the sense that reshaping didn't work

Comment: You have a flat list of 7826 values, right? 7826 / 12 = 652.1666666666666. So it's not possible to reshape.

Comment: That makes sense. I want to split my tuple into 12 columns, so that I can have a 12x7826 matrix. Is there any way to do that without iterating?

Comment: Tell us about `arr` - shape and dtype.  Your initial display looks like a list of tuples.  What's the relation between that and the `arr`?

Comment: @hpaulj I've edited the question to better explain what arr looks like

Comment: OK, that looks like a multifield `structured array`.  It is 1d, not 2.  You reference fields by name `arr['200-5']`.  You cannot `reshape` it to 2d.  However the `int` fields could be selected and "exported" to a 2d array with `structured_to_unstructured`. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#numpy.lib.recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured